# Exporting Data to Excel Template But Saves Under a Different Name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am able to use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to export data from Access to Excel, however, I want to be able transfer data into a specific sheet within an Excel template (e.g. Tasking.xls), that will then save under a different name (e.g. Tasking 20140429.xls).  The other sheets within the Excel template contain pivots etc. so they will need updating during this process.  The Excel template should just close down and remain in its original format.

This process will occur once a week so the dates will have to change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` to write into Tasking.xls directly.

I would either write a macro inside the Tasking.xls which reads in the XLS file you've exported using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` and updates the pivot tables and other sheets accordingly; or I would write a similar macro inside your database.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to transfer data into a template in Excel:

```
FileCopy "\\1dc.com\common\OMA_COMMON1\HRDEX\Corporate Reporting\Spans and Layers\Spans & Layers MASTER_TEMPLATE.xlsb", _
"\\1dc.com\common\OMA_COMMON1\HRDEX\Corporate Reporting\Spans and Layers\Spans & Layers MASTER_" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".xlsb"

xlsxDestinationWorkbook = "\\1dc.com\common\OMA_COMMON1\HRDEX\Corporate Reporting\Spans and Layers\Spans & Layers MASTER_" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".xlsb"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "QRY_HEADCOUNT_OA_DETAIL", xlsxDestinationWorkbook, False, "Headcount Detail"
```

One issue I did experience was that a new tab was created with the same name as the one I was looking to import into and calling the table "Headcount Detail1".  I got around this with the following steps:

1. format that new tab1 exactly as I wanted it
2. select the data on the tab, and CLEAR THE CONTENTS (do not delete it)
3. delete the original tab I had created in the template
4. rename tab1 to the name of the tab I just deleted
5. save the template